# non uniqueness for the solution of the following Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

The following Cauchy Problem:

$$y'=-10 \sqrt y,~~~ y(0) =\dfrac 14$$

doesn't have a unique solution, is that correct? I tried to solve that, and the solution is a parabola, but what I think is that when the parabola reach zero then there is also another solution which is the first part of the parabola and then the solution $y=0$.

The solution for the diff. eq. is $y(x) = \frac14(1-10x)^2$, but when $x=1/10$ the parabola reaches zero and then there is another solution which is $y(x) = \frac14(1-10x)^2$ for $x<1/10$ and $y=0$ for $x\ge1/10$.

Moreover I need to compute the absolute stability interval for Forward Euler applied to the previous ODE. I know how to compute it for the test equation (linear case), but I don't know how to deal with this particular case.

Comment: Try solving it first

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't verify the conditions of the theorem. Can you state the theorem and check the conditions for that particular ODE ?

Comment: Could you show your results ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the equation one can note first that

- $y$ has to be always non-negative and
- the slope $y'$ is always negative or zero for $y=0$.

This means that the solution that is initially parabolic gets then absorbed by the $x$-axis, there can be no solution that follows the rising parabolic branch after touching the $x$-axis.

---

A-stability of the Euler method for an ODE $y'=f(y)$ means roughly that if $\lambda=f'(y_n)<0$, and $y_n$ is close to a fixed point or an asymptote of the equation, then one wants that $λh_n=h_nf'(y_n)\in (-2,0)$, better closer to zero than the other side.

Here $f'(y)=-5y^{-\frac12}$ so that $0<h_n<\frac25\sqrt{y_n}$ as a guideline. With a fixed step size this bound is eventually violated. Let's see what happens in variable step size.

Selecting for instance $h_n=\frac15\sqrt{y_n}$, this gives the iteration
$$
y_{n+1}=y_n+h_nf(y_n)=y_n-2y_n=-y_n
$$
which is obviously not what is desired. So the guideline seems only useful if the local Lipschitz constant can be bounded.

Let's try a smaller $h_n=\frac1{20}\sqrt{y_n}$, then
$$
y_{n+1}=y_n-\frac12y_n=\frac12y_n\implies y_n=2^{-n}y_0.
$$
It follows that $h_n=\frac1{20}2^{-n/2}\sqrt{y_0}$, but
$$
t_n=h_0+h_1+\dots+h_{n-1}
=\frac1{20}\frac{1-2^{-n/2}}{1-2^{-1/2}}\sqrt{y_0}
<\frac{1+2^{-1/2}}{10}\sqrt{y_0},
$$
so that the time steps can not move the time over this finite boundary, which is also not what is expected of a solution.

Comment: So there is only one solution which is the first part of the parabola and then y=0 ?

Comment: Yes. It is only when starting with $y(x_0)=0$ that you get multiple solutions in this equation, the split occurring someplace to the left, in direction $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: well in this particular case also in y(x0)=0 you have only one solution which is y=0, because as you said the slope is always negative or zero so you can't take the solution which is the rising parabolic branch after y(x0)=0, or am i wrong?

Comment: Only if you only look "forward". "Turning time back", you can go along the $x$ axis as long as you want in negative direction and then branch off of it in the parabolic arc.

Comment: ok thanks, all clear. Just one more question. I have to study the absolute stability region using Forward Euler of the previous Cauchy problem. At this point this seems useless, because it is always absolutely stable for step size positive, since the solution at a certain point  is y=0.

Comment: Actually, you have to be careful with that. Approaching $y=0$, the local Lipschitz constant diverges to infinity which means that the step size of Euler has to converge to zero. In practice that means that the Euler steps with constant step size will very likely lead to negative $y$ values where the ODE does not exist. One could extend the ODE and make the $x$-axis attractive by declaring it for $y<0$ via $$y'=-10\,\text{sign}(y)\sqrt{|y|}.$$

Comment: Ok, so if i don't extend the ODE, can i say something about the absolute stability?

Comment: Short question: What is "absolute stability"? The explicit Euler method is not A-stable, but you seem to have a concept that is equally based on the ODE and the method?

Comment: Ok, but with the argument about the variable step size, what have we proved?

Comment: That the switching from the parabola to the $x$-axis is a very hard numerical task. You will even get problems with more advanced numerical solvers. The $x$-axis is essentially a singularity of the problem, even if it does not look like it from the shape of the solutions.